# Insert 1 million records into cassandra (simple benchmark)

Tags: node.js, cassandra, bigdata

I want to insert 1 million records into Cassandra for speed testing in Nodejs. I made a loop for setting data and batch for inserting data. But it works under 700 repeat. When I set my loop to 1,000,000, insert does not work!!

My node code by 'Cassandra-driver' rpm package:

```
const queries = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    queries.push({query: 'INSERT INTO subscribers (id, email , name , family) VALUES (?, ?, ? , ?)',
            params: [ uuidV4() , 'email@man' + i + '.com', 'test name' , 'test family']});
}

var before = new Date().getTime();
client.batch(queries, { prepare: true }, function(err){
    var after = new Date().getTime();
    resp.send('added recounds in : ' + (after - before) );
});
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Nothing and the query take time but do not insert anything into the table when the loop is more than 700. I`m looking for a way to inserting 1 million records. I've done it in MongoDB for 10 millions records.

Comment: so are you suggesting this is an issue with casandra driver ,as you were able to so the same with mongo..

Comment: No I`m looking for a code that I can insert 1 million records into Cansandra. My code does not work more than 700 in my loop.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are trying to create a single batch of 1M rows - there is a limit on the size of the batch and the recommendation is to have iot in the order of 10s  (https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/d318d2bde3248c297545704910291c0d0896ddcd/doc/features/batch/README.md)

Comment: I agree with @ShlomiLivne .  You cannot use BATCH in Cassandra in the same way that you would for a relational database.  Get rid of batch and try running your INSERTs without it.